# JQuery. Finding div which has specific data() associated to it

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using the `data()` function I add two values to some `divs` (`$oRow` points to divs)

```
$oRow.data("more", {moreValue: 750, moreIndex: 4});
```

Later on I'm trying to find the `div` (there is only one) which has a specific value for `moreIndex`

I'm doing it like so:

```
$oMore = $(".meter_battery_row").filter(function(){
                   return $.data(this, "more").moreIndex == 4;
                   });
```

But it doesn't seem to work. After the above line I display `window.alert($oMore)` but it seems it doesn't get to this line, so it runs in some kind of problem in the filter  function.

Anyone got any ideas?

**EDIT**

`.meter_battery_row` are the classes of `divs` to which i attach the data values. (`$oRow` is of class `.meter_battery_row`)

Comment: It works fine with me http://jsfiddle.net/Calou/Qjyhz/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add it data- attribute so you can retrieve it easier after and still use `$.fn.data()` :

```
$oRow.attr('data-moreIndex', 4).attr('data-moreValue', 750);
// ...
$oMore = $('.meter_battery_row[data-moreIndex="4"]');
```

Here is [a live example](http://jsfiddle.net/Calou/Qjyhz/4/).

Answer (score 1):

```
$('div.meter_battery_row[data-moreIndex="4"]') does not help you ?
```

normally the `.data()` function add's the custom value to your div as a `data-...` prefixed attribute.

You could use [attribute selectors](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) to get your specified div.

Inspect the element you are trying to select with firebug and  you will see that your moreIndex is saved as an attribute to the div element.

Comment: `$.fn.data` doesn't actually add the data-smthng attribute, you have to use `$.fn.attr`.

Answer (score 1):

First check `$.data(this, "more")`

```
return  ($.data(this, "more") && $.data(this, "more").moreIndex == 4);
```

Otherwise you will receive an error when not all elements have more-data, and the filtering stops.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you call `$.data(this, "more")` only one of elements will return the object `{moreValue: 750, moreIndex: 4}`, the rest will return undefined. then when you call `undefined.moreIndex` you will get an error. try to do this:

```
 return $.data(this, "more") && $.data(this, "more").moreIndex == 4;
```